# ng-repeat not working within directive

Tags: angularjs, compilation, directive

I've created an Angular wrapper for drop.js which is a javascript library for popups.

All works great within the drop directive including normal Angular bindings except when using ng-repeat.

Here is a screenshot, notice the content of the popup has a value that is bound to the controller but the ng-repeat is not displaying any data.

[image: ng-repeat not show within popup]

[image: html of rendered directive]

Here's the full plunker:  http://plnkr.co/edit/plcUAWCRQ009blhY3nqF?p=preview

Here's an example usage:

```
<button>
    button text {{someValue}}

    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="thing in things">button text {{thing.code}} - {{thing.name}}</li>
    </ul>

    <drop classes='classes' position='position'>

        <div>
            Hello {{ $parent.someValue}}
          <br>

          <ul>
            <!-- here is the problem, ng-repeat does not compile correctly -->
            <li ng-repeat="thing in $parent.things">{{thing.code}} - {{thing.name}}</li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </drop>
</button>
```

Here's the directive code:

```
.directive('drop', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      classes: '=?',
      constrainToScrollParent: '=?',
      constrainToWindow: '=?',
      position: '=?',
      openOn: '=?'
    },
    template: '<div><div ng-transclude></div></div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
      var drop;
      var target = element[0].parentElement;
      var compiled = $compile(element[0].children[0].innerHTML);

      var initDrop = function() {
        if (drop) {
          drop.destroy();
        }

        // some default values go here if they weren't passed in....

        drop = new Drop({
          target: target,
          content: compiled(scope)[0],
          classes: scope.classes,
          constrainToScrollParent: scope.constrainToScrollParent,
          constrainToWindow: scope.constrainToWindow,
          position: scope.position,
          openOn: scope.openOn
        });
      }

      initDrop();

      // clean up element
      element[0].innerHTML = '';

      // some watchers go here....
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with the `transcludeFn`. I'm not sure if you need a `pre` and `post` function or if you can put the `transclude` function directly in the `link` (postLink). [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LpC5RXKTTfJbSbetrxqb?p=preview)

```
.directive('drop', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
          classes: '=?',
          constrainToScrollParent: '=?',
          constrainToWindow: '=?',
          position: '=?',
          openOn: '=?'
        },
        link: {
          pre: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude){
            transclude(scope, function(clone, scope) {
              element.append(clone);
            });
          },
          post:function (scope, element, attrs) {
              var drop;
              var target = element[0].parentElement;
              var compiled = $compile(element[0].children[0]);

              var initDrop = function() {
                if (drop) {
                  drop.destroy();
                }

                if (typeof scope.classes == 'undefined') scope.classes = 'drop-theme-arrows-bounce';
                if (typeof scope.constrainToScrollParent == 'undefined') scope.constrainToScrollParent = true;
                if (typeof scope.constrainToWindow == 'undefined') scope.constrainToWindow = true;
                if (typeof scope.position == 'undefined') scope.position = 'top center';
                if (typeof scope.openOn == 'undefined') scope.openOn = 'click';

                drop = new Drop({
                  target: target,
                  content: compiled(scope)[0],
                  classes: scope.classes,
                  constrainToScrollParent: scope.constrainToScrollParent,
                  constrainToWindow: scope.constrainToWindow,
                  position: scope.position,
                  openOn: scope.openOn
                });
              }

            initDrop();

            // clean up element
            element[0].innerHTML = '';

            ...
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Top skills @mamawalter!